# Sending and receiving data over Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) using Telit BlueMod+SR

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

We are looking at using the [Telit BlueMod+SR](http://www.telit.com/bluetooth/bluemod-sr/) chip in a hardware idea we are working on. Towards that I've been trying to build a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) *server* simulation using the Telit BlueEva+SR evaluation board driven over USB by a Python script.

The two relevant manuals appear to be:

- BlueMod+SR AT Command Reference
- Terminal I/O Profile Client Implementation Guide (though I'm implementing the server)

(N.B. these are available [here](http://www.telit.com/download-zone/) but are behind a register/login.)

I'm stuck on something basic: how to send or receive data. I understand that this is done by setting the value of a Generic Attribute Profile (GATT) service's characteristic. The BlueMod+SR already has the GATT service characteristics that I need (a UART data TX characteristic and a UART data RX characteristic) on its Terminal I/O Service. The UUID's of the characteristics I need are given in the Terminal I/O Profile Client Implementation Guide but I cannot see how to read from nor write to them. The AT Command Reference has a section on GATT Server commands but the only one listed, `+LEATTRIB`, is for *defining* the attributes for a service (and the ones I need are already defined).

What are the commands I need to read and write the values for the characteristics UART Data TX, UART Data RX, UART Credits TX, and UART Credits RX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I did not need to use the credit mechanism, that's handled for me. So to write to the TX characteristic I can either connect to BLE and just write the data, or use the multiplexing and write the data to channel 0x01 (Terminal I/O). Reading the RX characteristic si similarly just reading the serial connection.